# Passing JQuery values to a PHP file using AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**AJAX codes**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../updateDB.php",
    data: {
        field: idValue[0],
        newValue: newValues,
        firstName: idValue[2],
        lastName: idValue[3]
    },
    success: function(){

    }  
});
```

**PHP File (updateDB.php)**

```
$field = $_POST['field'];
$newValue = $_POST['newValue'];
$firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
```

I want to pass the values from my JQUERY file to my PHP file. HELP!! Thank you!

Comment: what problems are you having?

Comment: i am not really shure if relative paths in url will work

Comment: I cant seem to pass the values field, newValue, firstName and last name to my PHP file

Comment: have you tried debugging your code? so what exactly is the problem? here's a similar post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218063/php-jquery-pass-value-through-ajax-to-php-and-check-against-variable?rq=1

Comment: Yaar....show us the array

Comment: the fields to be passed must be stored in phpMyAdmin. Is there something wrong with my code? Thanks for all the replies!

Comment: idValue = [mobile, 0927876988, juan, cruz]

Comment: Please try to use the absolute URL instead of ../updateDB.php and look at your results in firebug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

> ```
>    $.post( 'updateDB.php',
>    {
>        'field'         : idValue[0],
>        'newValue'      : newValues,
>        'firstName'     : idValue[2],
>        'lastName'      : idValue[3]
>    },
>    function( data )
>    {
>        $('#response').html( data );
>    });
> ```

Include the following on your page (to show the server response):

> ```
>    <div id="response"></div>
> ```

Then put the following into your PHP script to dump the posted values right back to the web page (to give you a visual queue that things are working):

> ```
>    echo "<pre>" . print_r( $_REQUEST, true ) . "</pre>";
> ```

You can access the individual values using

> ```
>    $field  = $_REQUEST['field'];
>    $newVal = $_REQUEST['newValue'];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ajax function in PHP file then you can use this way

```
 data: { 
         field: '<?=$field?>', 
         newValue: '<?=$newValue?>', 
         firstName: '<?=$firstName?>', 
         lastName: '<?=$lastName?>'
       },
```

let me know is this helpfull?

Comment: Dude, that's the Update DB Script. Moreover, using short codes are not good.