# Pass variable from JavaScript to PHP on new page

Tags: php, javascript, variables

I am pretty new to JavaScript and PHP.

I'd like to create a JavaScript function that contains a variable, passes this on to PHP on another page and opens that page.

Here is what I got so far (not working):

**My JS:**

```
function test()
{
    $.ajax(   
    {
        url: "my-new-page.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: 
        {
            varJS: "XXX"
        },
            error:function(err)
            {
                alert(err.statusText);
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                window.open("my-new-page.php");
            }
        });
}
```

**My PHP (on the new page):**

```
$varPHP = $_POST['varJS'];
```

Comment: And what is the problem..?

Comment: possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218063/php-jquery-pass-value-through-ajax-to-php-and-check-against-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand your question, you just want a simple javascript function that redirects to another page / PHP-script with some params?

my-new-page.php

```
<?
$varPHP = $_GET['varJS'];
echo $varPHP;
?>
```

javascript

```
function reDirect(varJS) {
    var page='my-new-page.php?varJS='+varJS;
    document.location.href=page;
}

reDirect('test')
```

Answer (score 0):

To just open a new window passing it a variable, you can do that within a query string.

Simply call
  window.open("my-new-page.php?varJS=XXX);

And Handle Query String on my-new-page.php

-Shakir

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of using Ajax is that it doesn't take the user to a new page. Don't use Ajax.

If you need to make a POST request then generate a form and hidden inputs with `document.createElement` and friends, append it to the current document, and then call its `submit()` method.